# How to create bootstrap table with custom column width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a table using bootstrap. The code is given below:

**.aspx page**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUsersList" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" HeaderStyle-CssClass="info"></asp:GridView>
```

Now, through jquery I am binding the grid, as shown below:

```
function populateUsersList(response) {
console.log(response);
//alert(response[0].FirstName);
//$('#respVal').html(response[0].FirstName);

$('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').empty();

if (response.length > 0) {
    $('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').append('<tr><th class="col-lg-4 info">Name</th>\
                            <th class="col-lg-3 info">Login Id</th>\
                            <th class="col-lg-3 info">Email Id</th>\
                            <th class="col-lg-3 info">Phone No.</th>\
                            <th class="col-lg-3 info">Designation</th>\
                            <th class="col-lg-4 info">Reporting To</th>\
                            <th class="col-lg-3 info">Business</th>\
                            <th class="col-lg-3 info">User type</th></tr>');
    $.each(response, function (index, itemData) {
        $('#ChildContent_grdUsersList').append('<tr><td class="text-left">' + itemData.UserName + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.LoginId + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.EmailId + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.Phone + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.Designation + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.ReportingTo + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.BusinessAssigned + '</td>\
                                 <td class="text-left">' + itemData.UserType + '</td></tr>');
    });
}
```

}

I have used "col-lg-*" in  tag of the table. Now, I want to change the width of the columns. I tried removing "col-lg-*" and applying custom css (width). But, its not getting changed.

Can anybody guide me how to change the width of the bootstrap tables?

Comment: The col width specifiers must add up to 12, Yours (col-lg-3,col-lg-3,col-lg-3,col-lg-3,col-lg-4,col-lg-3,col-lg-3) does not.

Comment: I tried that also, with two "col-lg-3" columns and the rest with "col-lg-1". But, then I wanted to change the column sizes by adding extra css but nothing happened actually. Is there any other bootstrap class that I can use over here